# Assembly works, but shellcode does not

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm, shellcode

I have a x64 processor and I'm looking into shellcode.
I have the following code:

```
section .text
  global _start

_start:
   push rax
   mov rbx, 0x68732f6e69622f2f
   shr rbx, 0x8
   push rbx
   mov rdi, rsp
   ;mov rdi, com

   mov al, 59
   syscall
```

When compiled with the foolowing command:

```
nasm -g -f elf64 execve.asm
```

And linked with:

```
ld execve.o -o execve
```

It runs fine. It opens a shell. If i get the shellcode from it:

```
"\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
```

And use this C program:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char shellcode[] = "\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

    (*(void (*)()) shellcode)();

    return 0;
```

}
Compile it:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o ex2 ex.c
```

If run it returns a segmentation fault, but it should execute a shell. Why?
Help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that the `shellcode` array and its contents is actually put into the code segment, making it executable?

Comment: I would guess because the memory doesn't have execute permission.

Comment: Thanks for the replyes. I guess it has the permission to execute it as it was compiled with    gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o ex2 ex.c

Comment: @Ervin Try making `shellcode` a `static const` variable.

Comment: @fuz, that is unlikely to work because he hasn't made the data segment be executable, only the stack.

Comment: @fuz I have tried it just now but it still does not work

Comment: What compiler version?

Comment: @prl can You tell me how to enable the stack to be executable?

Comment: gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: `-z execstack` says to make the stack executable.

Comment: you can run `execstack -q ex2` to check that the executable is marked as requiring an executable stack. It should print `X`.

Comment: execstack -q ex2 prints: X ex2

Comment: What is your problem? You invoke undefined behaviour and that's what you get.

Comment: Is there some reason to load rbx with "//bin/sh" and then shift right, discarding the extra leading '/'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your standalone assembly depends on registers `rsi` and `rdx` being zeroed.
(As you can see from http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/
 `sys_execve` takes three arguments through registers `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx`, and Linux will also accept it if `rdi` is a correct filename and `rsi` and `rdx` are zero).

This may be the case when the program starts, but it's not when you run the instructions from within the
middle of a program.

Consequently if `rsi`, and `rdx` have garbage in them, the syscall will fail and the instruction stream
will continue executing the garbage bytes it'll find after the syscall instruction, eventually leading to a crash (this is indeed, what's happening in your case, as you can see if you run the program through `gdb`)

The simplest way to make the syscall succeed is by zeroing out 2nd and the third argument:

```
section .text
  global _start

_start:
   xor rax, rax
   xor rsi, rsi ; zero 2nd argument
   xor rdx, rdx ; zero 3rd argument
   push rax
   mov rbx, 0x68732f6e69622f2f
   shr rbx, 0x8
   push rbx
   mov rdi, rsp

   mov al, 59
   syscall
```

Corresponding C code:

```
int main(void)
{
 char shellcode[] =

"\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xf6\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
;
    ((void (*)()) shellcode)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the help! I will dive into it deeper to figure out the problem with my code.

Comment: @PSk, It looks like this code is assuming that rax is 0? (It is used to push the null terminator for argv.)

Comment: @prl yup, it did. I changed it, though. Now I'm zeroing it explicitly and I'm also zeroing the 2nd and 3rd argument to execve, while keeping the rest of the code the same. That should replicate the conditions at the start of a process, which caused the standalone example to succeed unlike C example that embedded it.

Comment: @PSkocik It is a really good explanation. I like it. Thank You for the help once again.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `\x6e`.

This causes segv because the exec fails and there isn't a return after the syscall.

Comment: Adding the missing 6e doesn't fix the problem, though.

Comment: Yeah, I just reported the first error I found. Not surprising there are others.

Comment: Thank You for the help. I did not know that i should add 6e to the end, but suprisingly it failed with the same error. It looks like the problem is in te execve call, and that is cousing the error, not the end of instructions.

Comment: There are 3 problems: 1) the path "/bin/sh" is "/bi/sh"; 2) rsi and rdx are not initialized before the syscall; 3) there is no return after the syscall (so it causes segv when the execv fails).

Comment: @prl The path is correct.

Comment: @PSk, in the original question, it is `\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x2f\x73\x68`.